# Login Using Google: Check if user has credit card and can pay via google wallet

Tags: oauth, google-play, android-pay

My web app allows users to login using their Google account. By this, the app was able to capture user's email and other basic information.

Is it possible to check if a user has credit card and possibly can pay via Google wallet?

Comment: Doubt it, as it would compromise the users security(and money).

Comment: How about checking if a user has credit card. Does not mean get the credit card details

Comment: Could you provide a bit of info about what you're trying to do with the info?

Comment: Google oauth provides/returns basic information about the Google user. I want to get/know information about credit card or Google wallet associated with the account

Comment: @AyushGupta Apple Pay and Payment Request API does it via canMakePaymentsWithActiveCard and canMakePayment Promise, respectively. It should be possible for google pay as well to build a preference for pre-selected payment method on checkout page